# Deploying simple helloworld lambda function (python) using Terraform script - error creating "test lambda"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a lambda function using terraform script
I get error saying "error creating lambda function" I have put the screen shot of the error also
[image: Error]

This is the terraform script:

I created a role in AWS Management console and gave a name as "Welcome-Lambda-Role". That is what I referred to that role in the script below. I don't know if that is the issue.

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-west-2"
  access_key = "xxz"
  secret_key = "yyyydtEyZtOaQVGF5h"
}
data "archive_file" "welcome" {
  type = "zip"
  source_file = "welcome.py"
  output_path = "outputs/welcome.zip"
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename = "outputs/welcome.zip"
  function_name = "welcome"
  handler = "welcome.hello"

  //created this role manually in AWS console and referred to that role in the next line
  role = "Welcome-Lambda-Role"
 
  //source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("lambda_function_payload.zip")
  runtime = "python3.7"
}
```

welcome.py file content

```
  def hello(event, context):
     print("Welcome to terraform")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `role` should be **ARN** of the role, not its name only:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "Welcome-Lambda-Role"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {

      filename      = "welcome.zip"
      function_name = "welcome"
      handler       = "welcome.lambda_handler"

      role          = data.aws_iam_role.role.arn
      
      runtime       = "python3.7"

}
```

or if you just want to hard code it:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {

      filename      = "welcome.zip"
      function_name = "welcome"
      handler       = "welcome.lambda_handler"

      role          = "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/service-role/Welcome-Lambda-Role"
      
      runtime       = "python3.7"

}
```

Comment: thank you Marcin. that error is gone. for some reason my welcome.py file that gets added to welcome.zip file has no content. thats why I am getting this error.

Comment: @Jason You haven't shown your `welcome.py`, maybe its empty or its in different locatoin? Your `archive_file` is correct.

Comment: sorry I forgot to put welcome.py. I added that to the orginal post above. sorry just getting up to speed on terraform. why do I need to upload welcome.zip. why can't it be welcome.py file itself?

Comment: @Jason Zip is your [lambda deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html#gettingstarted-package-zip). There is nothing wrong with your code or lambda function apart the `role` issue. If you have other issues (empty `welcome.py`) then its not represented in your question.

Comment: thank you Zip. I will go thru the link You shared. appreciatae your help. One question. Is it normal to deploy Lambda functions using Terraform scripts? I built a CI/CD Jenkins pipeline to deploy terraform scripts. My plan was to use that pipeline to deploy the Lambda functions thru that terraform scripts.